# What is the cost of manufacturing per item?

Tags: logarithms

A firm estimates that the total revenue, $R$, in dollars, received from the sale of $q$ items (in thousands of items) is $R = 100000 \log(1+1000q^{2}).$
The manufacturing cost $C$, in dollars, of making $q$ thousand items is
$C = 50000q.$

What is the cost of manufacturing per item?
 I am thinking if the equation is $50000q=100000 \log(1+1000q^{2})$, but I don't know how to solve it? Please guide me.

And what quantity should be produced to maximize profit? which I need the answer from this part to finish.

Thank you!

Comment: Profit = Revenue - Cost

Comment: if it costs $50000 q$ to produce $q$ thousand items them cost to produce one item is $50$.

Comment: Have you plotted the revenue and cost as a function of items for say $q$ between $0$ and $20$?

Comment: @vasya how did you calculate it ?

Comment: @AHusain  why between 0 and 20?

Comment: You know you have to produce at least 0 and 20 is just some relatively small value so that it won't take too long to plot. The 20 is flexible, but don't go too much higher.

Comment: so for the cost of manufacturing per item 
Do I have to plot the graph?